# How to know the sender of a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, onmouseover

In HTML, I have some images and a javascript function.

```
<img onmouseover="repl()" class="EN" ... />
<img onmouseover="repl()" class="FR" ... />
...
```

When user is on an image. I want to change my header text according to the language selected.

I need a way to have a "reference" to the sender of my function in javascript.
But I have no idea because I have not used javascript for years. Please Help me !

```
function repl() {

    // Missing Solution 
    // var lang = sender.attr("class"); <= Please correct me

    var headerText = "";
    if (lang == 'FR') {
        headerText = "Cliquez sur le drapeau"
    } else {
        headerText = "Click on flag"
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best solution would be to bind the event using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).  Give all your images the same class, select them, then add events.  I also suggest using [`data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) to store the language.

```
<img class="repl" data-lang="EN" ... />
<img class="repl" data-lang="FR" ... />
```

Then in your JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function(){// Make sure DOM is ready
    // Get the images
    var imgs = document.getElementsByClassName('repl');

    // Loop over them
    for(var i = 0, len = imgs.length; i < len; i++){
        // Add the event
        imgs[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
            // Get the language. "this" is the element we hovered over
            var lang = this.getAttribute('data-lang');

            var headerText = "";
            if (lang == 'FR') {
                headerText = "Cliquez sur le drapeau"
            } else {
                headerText = "Click on flag"
            }
        });
    }
};
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/cT7Tj/1/

Answer (score 3):

First you need to send the sender to your function:

```
<img onmouseover="repl(this)" class="EN" ...
```

Then:

```
function repl(sender) {
//you have the element that sent the event
    var lang = sender.getAttribute('data-lang');
    var headerText = "";
    if (lang == 'FR') {
        headerText = "Cliquez sur le drapeau"
    } else {
        headerText = "Click on flag"
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot "this" as parameter. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

`var lang = this.getAttribute('class');`

You should rather use a "data-lang" attribute.

Comment: Thanks I never used data-lang. I am going to read more about that.

Comment: data-* attributes are used defined attributes espacially made to store data related to the dom element they belong to. In your case you could create a data-lang to store the language attribute that can then be accessed using jQuery's .data() or domNode.dataset.lang

Answer (score -1):

```
    function repl() {

   var lang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage; //this will fetch the current browser language   
   var headerText = "";

   switch (lang) {
       case 'fr':
           document.getElementById('your_id').innerHTML = "Cliquez sur le drapeau";
           break;
       default:
           document.getElementById('your_id').innerHTML = "Click on flag"
   }
```

Comment: But you never set `lang`...?

Comment: That's a good idea to get the navigator language as a default language. I keep that in mind.